# this.template.querySelector is not returning list of objects in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, queryselector

I have a requirement where I have to make a checkbox checked/unchecked based on the boolean field on Case object. When I am trying to select the element using querySelector, its not returning the list of selected nodes. Am I missing something?

```
<template if:true={lineOfBusiness}>
    <div class="row first-selection-menu">
        <div class="first-selection-combobox">
            <h1 class="combobox-label">Line of Business</h1>
            <lightning-combobox
                label="Line of Business"
                variant="label-hidden"
                name="lineofBusiness"
                value={value}
                placeholder="Select the line of business"
                options={lineOfBusinessPicklistValues}
                onchange={handleLineBusinessChange}
            >
            </lightning-combobox>
        </div>
        <template if:true={showIsEscalated}>
            <div class="escalated-checkbox">
                <!-- Shuchi -->
                <!-- <input type="checkbox" id="escalated" name="escalated" onchange={handeEscalation} /> -->
                <input type="checkbox" data-id="escalated" name="escalated" onchange={handeEscalation}/>
                <label for="escalated" class="checkbox-label"
                    >Technical Escalation to an expert
                </label>
            </div>
        </template>
</template>
```

---

```
handleSelectedMain(event) {
    this.mainSelectionValue = event.target.value;
    if (this.mainSelectionValue === 'Transfer Case') {
        this.lineOfBusiness = true;
        if (this.showIsEscalated) {
            console.log(this.template.querySelector('[data-id="escalated"]'));// getting proxy object
        console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(this.template.querySelector('[data-id="escalated"]')))); // getting proxy object
                       this.template.querySelector('[data-id="escalated"]').checked = getFieldValue(
            this.caseRecord,
            ESCALATION_FLAG
        );
        }
    }
    this.showMainHelp = false;
}
```

[image: Proxy object]

Comment: Hello. Try this.template.querySelectorAll(). It should return a list. The querySelector() method returns the first element that matches a CSS selector.

Comment: Thanks @Konstantin for your input but this also did not work. Tried below.
console.log(this.template.querySelectorAll("div")); Getting Proxy like vefore

Comment: @SHUCHITIWARI : How are you setting showIsEscalated flag ? Can you debug by removing it from both HTML & JS  and check if it works ?

Comment: This is setting to true. I checked in debug. The flow is coming to this point. So do not understand the point of removing it.

Comment: Then there would be some condition other than showIsEscalated due to which checkbox is not rendering. Can you post the complete HTML? I tried your code snippet and it works fine.

Comment: ok let me post the entire code, but what I found are 2 boolean which I checked is true before selecting element so it should be there. That is why I tried to select the div element which has to be there but could not find anything in the selector. Also I checked in dev tool and can see that node. Updated my post with more HTML. If you can have a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Proxy` is a tool used by developers to trap certain events. Lightning Locker Service and Lightning Web Security uses a `Proxy` to ensure that data is accessed correctly.

As a simple demonstration to this, consider the following code:

```
let x = new Proxy({}, { get() { return 'Hello World'; } });
console.log(x.aMessage); // 'Hello World';
console.log(x.anotherMessage); // 'Hello World';
```

Here, we create a trap that always returns the same value, no matter the input.

It's helpful to note in the previous example, that running code does not see it as a Proxy:

```
console.log(x instanceof Proxy); // won't return true here
```

As far as your running code is concerned, the returned element is whatever is inside the `Proxy`.

With that out of the way, the next thing to note is that `querySelector` returns just one `Element`, not a `NodeList` that `querySelectorAll` would. We expect to receive a single `Element` wrapped in a `Proxy` that is transparent to the code.

However, note that there is the [Component Lifecycle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks). Changes you make to a property are not immediately rendered as a new version, you must wait for a render cycle. `setTimeout` is not recommended, so your best option is to add an asynchronous wait.

We do that with a combination of `async` to indicate the function is wrapped in a `Promise`, and we use `await Promise.resolve()` to allow the DOM to update before continuing.

```
async handleSelectedMain(event) {
    this.mainSelectionValue = event.target.value;
    if (this.mainSelectionValue === 'Transfer Case') {
        this.lineOfBusiness = true;
        // Allow the DOM to update.
        await Promise.resolve();
        if (this.showIsEscalated) {
            this.isEscalatedValue = this.caseRecord.data.fields.IsEscalated.value;
            //want to check/uncheck the checkbox based on above field value. Tried using value attribute on input checkbox node and used this property      there.Not working as well
            console.log(this.template.querySelector("div")); // getting proxy object, image attached
            console.log(this.template.querySelector("input"));
            console.log(this.template.querySelector('[data-id="escalated"]')); //getting null in console
            // this.template.querySelector('[data-id="escalated"]').checked = this.caseRecordDetail.data.fields.IsEscalated.value; 
            // tried setting checked on the element but not working as element is not selected may be
        }
    }
    this.showMainHelp = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing @sfdcfox , 1 question though : setTimeout is not used since it makes difficult to track page performance. How is Promise.resolve different from it and does not cause this issue?

Comment: @Rohit Promises themselves are still inherently synchronous, just allow for asynchronous things to happen. Here, what happens is the current event handler stops and hands control back to the lifecycle system. As soon as the render completes, JavaScript immediately comes back to our control for the rest of the handler. In that sense, it's not asynchronous. If that's not clear enough, consider what happens when you use a generator: `function* range(i = 0, s = 10) { while(i < s) { yield i++; } }`. This code bounces between itself and the caller, but isn't asynchronous.

Comment: Great !!! The yield example helped me to understand. I learned something new today. Thank you @sfdcfox, Upvoted the answer.  This comment can also be added in the answer since it nicely explains the difference.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for the soultion. It worked.

Comment: @sfdcfox I am still unable to prnt that in console. It still appears as proxy. Tried JSON methods but did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @SHUCHITIWARI Can you edit your question to include the new/changed code? I'd be happy to look at it with you.